# How do i fix dns problem with dsl pppoe connection? Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I've configured /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head like that:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 1.1.1.1 
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

That is my /ets/resolv.conf file :

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 1.1.1.1 
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

So everything works fine. The problem is that i lose my internet connection in every 1 or 2 hours and get dns_probe_finished error. Which can be solved by turning off and turning on the connection most of the time. And sometimes I need to restart my computer to get the internet connection again. So can anyone help me with that?